# Could not load program git-remote-http in AIX 7.1

Tags: git, aix

Has anyone come across the below issue ? I installed git (git version 2.20.1) AND  I am getting when I run it in my AIX 7.1 box.

```
$ git clone http://bitbucket.xxxxxx/scm/clr/clr-my.git
Cloning into 'clr-my'...
Could not load program git-remote-http:
Symbol resolution failed for git-remote-http because:
        Symbol _GLOBALAIXI_libcurl_so (number 206) is not exported from dependent
          module /opt/freeware/lib/libcurl.a[libcurl.so.4].
        Symbol _GLOBALAIXD_libcurl_so (number 207) is not exported from dependent
          module /opt/freeware/lib/libcurl.a[libcurl.so.4].
Examine .loader section symbols with the 'dump -Tv' command.

$ ls -lrt /opt/freeware/lib/libcurl.a
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     system      1644689 Jun 18 2018  /opt/freeware/lib/libcurl.a

$ ls -lrt | grep libcurl.so.4
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     system       756861 Jun 18 2018  libcurl.so.4
```

Comment: Where from did you install `curl` and `git`? They seems to have been compiled with incompatible settings. (That's why some experts prefer installing programs from source rather than from binary package.)

Comment: I used rpm to install. I don't have yum installed.Moreover, this is a controlled environment which we are not given to set-up apps using sources

Comment: URL : https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/aix-toolbox-linux-applications-downloads-alpha,           http://www.oss4aix.org/download/RPMS/curl/                    We are migrating to DevOps so we need to to create Jenkins jobs and to download the source from bit bucket, we use git.

Comment: Do you have `/opt/freeware/lib` in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Comment: Thank you for the support.  I managed to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have installed incompatible packages from different sources, eg: https://public.dhe.ibm.com/aix/freeSoftware/aixtoolbox/RPMS/ppc/git/git-2.20.1-1.aix6.1.ppc.rpm and http://www.oss4aix.org/download/RPMS/curl/curl-7.65.3-1.aix5.1.ppc.rpm

Instead, install all your packages from the same source, eg: https://public.dhe.ibm.com/aix/freeSoftware/aixtoolbox/RPMS/ppc/git/git-2.20.1-1.aix6.1.ppc.rpm and https://public.dhe.ibm.com/aix/freeSoftware/aixtoolbox/RPMS/ppc/curl/curl-7.65.1-1.aix6.1.ppc.rpm

That way your shared objects will agree on their global symbols, eg:

```
dump -Tv -X32 /opt/freeware/libexec/git-remote-http | grep '_GLOBAL.*AIX.*curl'
[205]   0x00000000    undef      IMP     DS EXTref libcurl.a(libcurl.so.4) _GLOBAL__AIXI_libcurl_so
[206]   0x00000000    undef      IMP     DS EXTref libcurl.a(libcurl.so.4) _GLOBAL__AIXD_libcurl_so

dump -Tv -X32 /opt/freeware/lib/libcurl.a | grep '_GLOBAL.*AIX.*curl'
[444]   0x200018c0    .data      EXP     DS   Ldef        [noIMid] _GLOBAL__AIXI_libcurl_so
[445]   0x200018cc    .data      EXP     DS   Ldef        [noIMid] _GLOBAL__AIXD_libcurl_so
```

So right now I suggest removing `curl` package (and `curl-devel` too, if installed) from OSS4AIX, and install the one from IBM AIX Toolbox.